# AWS EC2 SFTP server permission denied

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, putty, winscp

I have configured a new user with password and then tried to connect to is over SFTP using WinSCP but it says permission denied.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the username as per the OS, for ubuntu LTS the user name is ubuntu. So the command is :

sftp -i /path/your-key.pem ubuntu@aws-public-ip-address